# Is it possible to add a description for request params in Swagger?

Tags: java, swagger, documentation, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I have an API endpoint meant to fetch appointment information. Among the parameters this endpoint takes are "from" and "to" dates, representing the date range for appointments that it will fetch. They currently show up in my Swagger like so:
[image]

I'm wondering if I might be able to augment the Swagger with a short description to explain that the endpoint will fetch appointments that have a start time that falls within this range and that the range is inclusive. Is this possible to do?

The current declaration for this endpoint in my controller looks like this

```
    @Operation(summary = "Get the list of appointments")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(
                responseCode = "200", description = "List of appointments",
                content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = AppointmentDTO.class))}
        )
})
@GetMapping("/{businessId}/appointment")
public ResponseEntity<List<AppointmentDTO>> getAppointments(@PathVariable UUID businessId,
                                                            @RequestParam(required = false) List<UUID> providerIds,
                                                            @RequestParam(required = false) List<UUID> consumerIds,
                                                            @RequestParam(required = false) List<AppointmentStatus> status,
                                                            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "from") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") Date fromDate,
                                                            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "to") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") Date toDate,
                                                            Pageable pageable) {
```

Comment: You probably need `@Parameter(description="...")` - see [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#parameter)

Comment: That was it, thank you. If you want to add an answer with this instead of a comment I can mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

@Parameter annotation does the work.
Ensure to import the one from import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;

```
public ResponseEntity<CustomerDTO> fetchCustomer(
        @Valid @Parameter(description = "customerId for which you want to fetch the details") @RequestParam(name = "customerId", required = true) String customerId){// your logic here}
```

In the above example, I am able to describe the use of the paramater customerId using @Paramater.

You can find more details [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation).